# Select a random point on a line of a polygon

Tags: java, geometry, awt, polygon, computational-geometry

I'm using a Java Polygon object, which stores an array of points which define the lines that make up the shape.

How would I go about selecting a random point on one of these lines? Are there any methods in the Polygon class that would make this easier?

To clarify, I want to pick a random point from any position on the edge of the polygon, not necessarily from the set of defined vertices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is find the perimeter of the polygon.

Now find a random number the range of 0 to perimiter.

Then, iterate over the segments of the polygon, subtracting the length of the segment from your value until the length of the next segment is longer than your current value.

Pretend you're "walking that distance" along the segment equal to your remaining value, and you'll have a random point on the perimeter.

## ================================

Another viable option would be to pick a random segment biased by their length (you could cache the thresholds for each polygon) and then pick a random point on the segment that was randomly picked. Would be faster for large polygons (order 1 after you cache the thresholds) but would go through twice the random numbers.

Comment: +1 - these approaches give *evenly distributed* random points on the perimeter.

Answer (score 2):

Use point-slope form to create a `y = mx + b` equation for a randomly chosen edge out of one of the `n` edges that connect the vertices. Vertices are defined in `Polygon.xpoints` and `Polygon.ypoints`.

**Consider the following:**
Suppose we have a pentagon. We have 5 edges and 5 vertices. Since we have vertices stored in `Polygon` and want an edge, we need two vertices to form a line, so we randomly choose between `0` and `5`. Suppose our randomly generated number `r = 0`.

Suppose `xpoints[r] = 1`, `ypoints[r] = 1`, `xpoints[r+1] = 2`, and `ypoints[r+1] = 4`.

For `m`, we have

```
m = (4-1)/(2-1) = 3
```

For point-slope form, we have

```
(y - 1) = m(x - 1)
(y - 1) = 3(x - 1) --> y = 3x - 2
```

Now, choose a random `x` between the two x-bounds for this edge, i.e. in the domain `[0,2]`, and you have your random points `(x, y(x))`.

Comment: Also, notice what happens if `r = 5`, we have array index of 6 which is out of bounds. For `r = 5`, instead of doing `r+1` to get the next vertex, we use `0`.

Answer (score -1):

If you have n points in the array use the java Random class.

```
java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
int num = r.nextInt(n); // n is the highest random number generated, also the size of the array
fuctionThatUsesPoint(myPolygon.xpoints[num], myPolygon.ypoints[num]);
```

Comment: He want a random point on one of the lines ... not a random apex

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it more clear in the question. I want to pick a random point from any position on the edge of the polygon, not necessarily from the set of defined vertices.

Comment: @Matt - the Question was clear enough, as originally written, IMO.